# Mocking function in React class component using Jest produces "type is invalid" error

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, react-testing-library

I'm writing tests using Jest for a custom DataTable component. I'm also using React Testing Library.

The component loads an iframe when a row is clicked. I'm attempting to mock the function that loads the iframe and I'm getting an error message when running the test that uses the mock. For context, the goal of mocking this function is preventing the test from loading the actual iframe.

The full error message is: `Warning: React.jsx: type is invalid -- expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: object.`

My understanding is that this error message usually happens when you're incorrectly importing a module. However, I don't believe this is my case because the component is being imported and used in other tests and it works fine in those tests. It's only the component with the mocked function that produces this error.

How would I mock this function? The function is `loadIframe(id)` and it's in a class component. The code for the component and the test code is below.

Stripped down version of the component with the function I want to mock:

```
class MyDataTable extends React.Component {
    ...
    
    // I want to mock this function
    loadIframe(id = "") {
        this.setState({iframe: `/path/to/iframe/${id}`})
    }
    
    ...
    
    render() {
        return (
            ...
            
            {this.state.iframe !== "" &&
                <iframe src={this.state.iframe}/>
            }
            
            ...
        )
    );
}
export default MyDataTable;
```

Code for the tests:

```
import "@testing-library/jest-dom";
import { render, screen, waitFor } from "@testing-library/react";
import userEvent from "@testing-library/user-event";
import axios from "axios";
import MyDataTable from "../../components/DataTable/MyDataTable";

jest.mock("axios");

jest.mock("../../components/DataTable/MyDataTable", () => ({
  ...jest.requireActual("../../components/DataTable/MyDataTable"),
  loadIframe: jest.fn((id) => {
    // this mocked implementation will need to do something, but I've removed it from this example
  })
}));

describe("My tests", () => {
  it("should load iframe on row click", async () => {
    const data = [
        ["row 1, col 1", "row 1, col 2"],
        ["row 2, col 1", "row 2, col 2"]
    ];
    // Need to make a mock POST request to get data so a row can be clicked
    axios.post.mockResolvedValue({ data });

    // The error is thrown when render() is called here
    render(<MyDataTable id="test_id"/>);

    await waitFor(() => expect(axios.post).toHaveBeenCalled());
    
    userEvent.click(screen.getAllByRole("gridcell")[0]);
    expect(screen.getByTitle("iframe")).toBeInTheDocument();
  });
});
```

Comment: First of all, This error message mean's  you try to mocking module `MyDataTable` as object type, That's why when you `render()` component `MyDataTable` you got that error message.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IMO, This case is unnecessary to test logic on function `loadIframe`. You just query selector that you wanna test and expect `src` attribute should be a value according to state change from function `loadIframe`.

```js
jest.mock("axios");

describe("My tests", () => {
    it("should load iframe on row click", async () => {
        const data = [
            ["row 1, col 1", "row 1, col 2"],
            ["row 2, col 1", "row 2, col 2"]
        ];
        // Need to make a mock POST request to get data so a row can be clicked
        axios.post.mockResolvedValue({ data });

        // The error is thrown when render() is called here
        const {container} = render(<MyDataTable id="test_id"/>);

        await waitFor(() => expect(axios.post).toHaveBeenCalled());

        userEvent.click(screen.getAllByRole("gridcell")[0]);
        const iFrame = container.querySelector('iframe')

        // this step is expect `src` attribute in iFrame element should be according to state change inside function `loadiFrame`
        expect(iFrame).toHaveAttribute('src','/path/to/iframe/1')
    });
});
```

Comment: Hi, I appreciate the suggestion but this won't work because the iframe is a HTML <iframe> element and not a component. I could make a component for it, but I'd prefer not to create a component that just wraps a single HTML element.

The purpose of the `loadIframe()` function is changing state to update the value of the `src` attribute for the <iframe> element. Without mocking this function, the `src` attribute will be changed to `localhost:3000/my/iframe/route` which will make an unnecessary network request. I only want to test whether the iframe element is rendered (not the iframe content).

Comment: ahh I got it, If you wanna test iFrame element should be render, I will edit my answer, you can scrolling up to watch it again.